# Does something like jQuery.toggle(boolean) exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I write something similar to the following code a lot. It basically toggles an element based on some condition.

In the following made-up example, the condition is "If the `agree` checkbox is checked and the `name` field isn't empty".

```
$("button").click(function() {
  if ($("#agree").is(":checked") && $("#name").val() != "" ) {
    $("#mydiv").show();
  } else {
    $("#mydiv").hide();
  }
});
```

I wish there was some sort of jQuery function that would work like this.

```
$("button").click(function() {
  var condition = $("#agree").is(":checked") && $("#name").val() != "" );
  $("#mydiv").toggle(condition);
});
```

Is there something like this out there?  Or are there other ways besides the first example to do this in a less `if-else-ish` way?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Ok, so I am an idiot and need to RTM before I ask questions.

[jQuery.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) allows you to do this out of the box.

```
$("button").click(function() {
  var condition = $("#agree").is(":checked") && $("#name").val() != "" );
  $("#mydiv").toggle(condition);
});
```

Comment: Do you know of a version of this function that supports easing/fading/sliding for the transition?  This particular method doesn't seem to, and it makes my page jump quite quickly in a way that's more confusing to users than a gentle slide.

Comment: Yep it was added in jQuery version 1.4.3. Look at the documentation page (http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle2) you'll see that there are three ways to call toggle() you want to use the following: .toggle( [ duration ], [ easing ], [ callback ] )

Comment: AFAIK you can't pass a boolean AND an duration/easing, etc. I'd love to stand corrected on however.

Comment: I will agree with the RTFM, only the name, toggle, is just not something you can think of looking for in this situation.

Comment: The entry that describes `toggle(boolean)` is actually this: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-setShown

Comment: Well, you saved me from RTFM—I just had to do a websearch. But maybe I'm an idiot too. 

Comment: this is awesome. Not found this even in jQuery's documentation. One more point that `.toggleClass` also works like this. Example: `.toggleClass('class-name', condition);`

Answer (score 8):

First, lets see if I understand what you want to do correctly...
You want to look at the state of a checkbox(checked or not) and hide or show a second div based on the status of that value.

Define this style:

```
.noDisplay {
    display:none;
}
```

Use this JavaScript:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $("#mydiv").toggleClass("noDisplay", $("#name").val() == "");
});
```

The documentation from jQuery on it can be found here:
http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 5):

You could write the function yourself.

```
function toggleIf(element, condition) {
    if (condition) { element.show(); }
    else { element.hide(); }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
toggleIf($("button"), $("#agree").is(":checked") && $("#name").val() != "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Syntax 4
$(selector).toggle(display)

display
true - to show the element.
false - to hide the element.

Answer (score 0):

If `toggle()` is not good for you (e.g. because it animates), you can write a small jQuery plugin, like this:

```
$.fn.toggleIf = function(showOrHide) {
  return this.each(function() {
    if (showOrHide) {
      return $(this).show();
    } else {
      return $(this).hide();
    }
  });
};
```

and then use it like this:

```
$(element).toggleIf(condition);
```

Comment: The `$.toggle()` function only animates when you pass a duration value as an argument. If you pass a boolean argument, it does *not* animate. So a plugin like this would be superfluous.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/qvdsu/